# Can't find Anaconda navigator or Anaconda prompt

Tags: anaconda

I install Anaconda vs 2019.10 on my Windows 10 but I couldn't find the shortcuts to it.
I've tried searching for it using CMD but it's returns the message that Anaconda can't be found 
And I can't also find jupyter notebook or spider

Comment: Can you be specific what exactly you installed, which Windows you are using and from which source you got it?

Comment: Please do not repost your questions, especially not twice within a few minutes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269588/cannot-see-anaconda-menu-shortcuts-after-installation-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Anaconda and **don't change the default settings**. Everything will work as expected. `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Anaconda3\condabin` will be added to your PATH and you'll only need to `conda activate` (or run the Anaconda-Prompt shortcut) to start using Python.

Comment: @Evans: Would you please consider replying to your post. Voluntarily helping you was some effort. So I guess I'm entitled to ask for a little respect ...